# Set enumerate counter to represent the section number

Tags: enumerate

The text will be like:

> Session 1
>
> Q 1.1
>
> a.
>
> b.
>
> c.
>
> Q 1.2
>
> Session 2
>
> Q 2.1
>
> a.
>
> b.
>
> c.
>
> Q 2.2

So on and hence forth.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE of your current code.

Comment: Also, what is a section/subsection/... in this example? Is Session a section? Chapter? We need an MWE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably like the following?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@ }%
  {-3.5ex\@plus -1ex\@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\noindent\normalfont \Large \bfseries Session\ }%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{}

\begin{enumerate}[label={Q.\thesection.\arabic*}]
\item question
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item subquestion
  \item subquestion
  \item subquestion
  \end{enumerate}
\item question
\end{enumerate}

\section{}

\begin{enumerate}[label={Q.\thesection.\arabic*}]
\item question
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item subquestion
  \item subquestion
  \item subquestion
  \end{enumerate}
\item question
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Apologies for absence of my foresight. @leandriis, I am making the second assignment set. Im this new set, the session number should start from 4. How do I make the changes.

Comment: Place `\setcounter{section}{3}` before the first `\section{}` command and the sections (sessions)  will be numbered starting from 4.

Answer (score 0):

This works on the assumption that you want to enumerate subsections and a Q in front of the section:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Q. \arabic{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}} 
\begin{document}

    \section{foo}
    foo
    \subsection{bar}
    bar
    \subsection{foobar}
    foobar
    \section{foo2}
    foo2
    \subsection{bar2}
    bar2
    \subsection{foobar2}
    foobar2
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Actually I am making a assignment. So there are set of questions that are based on Session 1. Then there are some questions that are based on session 2. I denote first section as Session 1. Now I want first question to numbered as 1.1 and second question from session 1 to be numbered as 1.2. The irst question based on session 2 will be numbered as 2.1, 2.2,.....

I hope it answers your question.